# How can one integrate the sum of the partial derivatives squared in x and y?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I ended up with this equation trying to derive an expression for the change in the area of a small parallelogram on a 3D surface, $h(x,y)$, is the height function,
$$\int_0^L \int_0^L \left[\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]dx\,dy.$$
Integration by parts doesn't produce anything useful (unless I already know the integral of $h(x)$),
$$\int_0^L  \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right)^2 dx = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\,h(x)\bigg|_0^L -\int_0^L h(x)\frac{\partial^2h}{\partial x^2} dx.$$
As vectors, $\frac{dh}{dx}$ and $\frac{dh}{dy}$ are tangents to the surface. Also, $\frac{dh}{dx}\times\frac{dh}{dy}$ would be the normal.
Is there a way to write these in spherical form $(r,\theta,\phi)$ or some other method to change the integrand into something more manageable?

Comment: Now firstly how on earth did you get this formula?

Comment: Are you sure your integrand is correct? I can't see where it could come from. Perhaps you should edit your question to fill in the derivation to that point.

Comment: Did it come from an integration by parts in $\int\int \Delta h(x,y)\;h(x,y)\;dx\,dy$, with boundary terms vanishing? This would be one way it would have some structural sense...